# Testing the website in Android mobile which is locally hosted in my laptop in XAMPP Server

Tags: android, xampp, web

I got a problem when i tried to test my website in my Android phone. I have installed XAMPP in my laptop and my page is perfectly running in my laptop web browser but when i tried check in my mobile phone web browser(using my local ip) I couldn't see any images and sliders placed in my website. ONLY TEXT ARE SHOWING UP.I am using a word press theme.

Thank you

Comment: Are the images also  placed in the XAMPP server , or you are getting them from a third party server ?

Comment: Images are also placed in the XAMPP server

Comment: did you try inspecting the webpage with google  chrome ?

Comment: In mobile??? i didnt

Comment: try this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ Maybe you will find some logs that can help you

Comment: ok.......i ll try